# Codeigniter session->userdata->username not show up after login

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I don't know what to do my username is not show up every time I log in... I mean, I could login perfectly but my username is not showing up...

**View:Home.php**

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       <?php echo $this->session->userdata("username");?>
       Member<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

**Controller:Login/loginMember.php**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {
    $this->load->view('front/login');
} else {
    //enter username and password
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('Member_model');
    $member = $this->Member_model->checkLogin($username, $password);
    if (!$member) {
       $data_session = array(
            'username' => $member->username,                
           'logged_in' => true);
       $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
       //redirect
       redirect('Member/profile');
     } else {
         print_r('User doesnt exist');
     }
}
```

**Model:Member_model/checkLogin.php

```
$this->db->select('password');
$this->db->from('member');
$this->db->where(array('username' => $username, 'password'=> $password));
$hash = $this->db->get()->row('password');
return $this->verify_password_hash($password, $hash);
if ($hash->num_rows() > 0) { 
    return $hash->row_array();
} else { 
    return FALSE; 
}
```

The view always like this:
[image: username on home]

The member in the pic name is not username but a word that i write after

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata("username");?>
```

So that it won't became null and combine in other menu

Comment: $member is object or array?

Answer (score 1):

Please set session_userdata like this:

```
$data_session = array(
            'username' => $member->username,                
           'logged_in' => true);
       $this->session->set_userdata('data_session',$data_session);
```

And then use it like this:

```
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('data_session');
    $username= $session_data['username'];
    $logged_in= $session_data['logged_in'];
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but, it goes to else after i use your code... so whenever i input the data it always goes t login page again and again

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `$member` if it has `username` data on it.

Or

Maybe you could just use the `$username` from `$username = $this->input->post('username');` though I'm not quite sure if there's any security concern on this kind of approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and model is not consistent

Inside controller you use $member->username, but in model you use $hash->row_array()

row_array() will return an associative array, so you have to access with $member['username']

use $hash->row(), if you want to use object and access it with $member->username

---

i'm not sure why you didn't see the error in you development system, you code should show some error if your enabling the error, 
For development purposes you should enable PHP error reporting, so you can error like that would be easier to track.

Answer (score 0):

First please make sure, your set_session working fine or not. using all_userdata() you can cross check current session data.

please use this code, and let me know what data stored in the session.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

It will print whole session data.